# Face Detection using javascript

Tags: mean-stack, face-detection, pos-tagger, tracking.js

As a part of learning MEAN stack development I decided do one social media demo application and It is working fine now, in my local mechine. The problem raised when I started to implement tagging option in group photo.I have an idea which is related to face detection.

The requirement is to detect the persons in group photo and the software itself need to tag those persons. So I implemented a face detection technique by using tracking.js and fetched the eye,mouth,face value in Mongodb during profile picture upload. And my need is to check these values during group photo post upload. But this idea didn't  meet my expectation.

So how I need to generate the data of face during each person's profile picture upload?.

So I just would like to know that how to implement this scenario in my project and what kind of implementation style is on facebook and picasa photo editor(desktop application) has already done. If anybody has done this before please help me.

Comment: There is an usefull library written in javascript, take a look: https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection

Comment: @C0dekid so can you suggest some good libraries. I Would like to implement my idea.

Comment: I've updated my comment, please see that github page :)